# EPIC FHIR sandbox Observation.create(Vitals)

Tags: hl7-fhir, epic

I would like to send measurements like blood pressure values to test patient's flowsheet in Epic sandbox. I have not figured out how to "place an order to create the episode and patient entered flowsheets" in Epic sandbox (https://fhir.epic.com/Specifications?api=963). Tried MyChart but I recon a physician role would be needed and maybe Hyperspace.
Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, Beibian

Comment: Have you asked open@epic.com?

Comment: Okay, let's try, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hi and I got the reply. Answer is that Epic sandbox does not support creating episodes which means that Observation.Create() etc works only in some customer's installation or customer's test environment